# Adding XElement inside a XML Element/Node in c# using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

i want to create some xml with this format

```
<root>
 <columns>
  <column name="name1" value="value1" />
  <column name="name2" value="value2" />
  <column name="name3" value="value3" />
  ...
 </columns>
 <rows>
  <row name="name1" value="value1" />
  <row name="name2" value="value2" />
  <row name="name3" value="value3" />
  ...
 </rows>
</root>
```

so i create a

```
XElement tree = new XElement("root", new XElement("columns", from c in  columns select new XElement("column", c) ...
```

And the result is

```
<root>
 <columns>
  <column>
   <column>
    <column> 
     ...
    </column>
   </column>
  </columns>
 ...
</root>
```

how can i close a node children or something to have what i want??

Comment: Please provide your full code.

Comment: I have edited please check.I think it is collapse

Comment: @Shrivallabh, you typed "colapse", I improved but, it turns out the **intended** verb is "close".

Comment: What is `columns` variable?

Answer (score 2):

Following code:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> columns = new Dictionary<string,string> {
   {"name1", "value1"},
   {"name2", "value2"},
   {"name3", "value3"}
}.ToList();

XElement tree =
    new XElement("root",
        new XElement("columns",
            from c in columns
            select new XElement("column",
                new XAttribute("name", c.Key),
                new XAttribute("value", c.Value)
            )
        ),
        new XElement("rows",
             from r in rows // same dictionary as columns 
             select new XElement("row",
                 new XAttribute("name", r.Key),
                 new XAttribute("value", r.Value)
            )
        )
    );
```

Produces required xml:

```
<root>
  <columns>
    <column name="name1" value="value1" />
    <column name="name2" value="value2" />
    <column name="name3" value="value3" />
  </columns>
  <rows>
    <row name="name1" value="value1" />
    <row name="name2" value="value2" />
    <row name="name3" value="value3" />
  </rows>
</root>
```

Comment: This is rendering me soomething like this... <root>
  <columns>
    <column name="name1" value="value1">
    <column name="name2" value="value2">
    <column name="name3" value="value3">
  </column></column></column></columns>
  <rows>
    <row name="name1" value="value1">
    <row name="name2" value="value2">
    <row name="name3" value="value3">
  </row></row></row></rows>
</root>

Comment: @user1977936 this should render same way on any PC. What is `columns` and `rows` variables in **your** code?

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky List of keyvaluepair

Comment: @user1977936 updated code with List of KeyValuePair, works as before

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement tree = new XElement("root",
    new XElement("columns",
        from c in columns
        select new XElement("column", new XAttribute("name", c.Name,), new XAttribute("value", c.Value))),
    new XElement("rows",
        from r in rows
        select new XElement("row", new XAttribute("name", r.Name,), new XAttribute("value", r.Value))));
```

Comment: same result... this is what i was having before